# Task list Due Date column

Tags: workflow, column, task-list, reusable-workflow

I have many problems in using a 2013 Reusable Workflow. 
I have to copy tasks from many task lists in the site to a single general list: in order to do it, I have created a Reusable Workflow and connected to the Content Type I am using for the task lists (and this was already quite a challenge!). 
Unfortunately I realized that the **Due Date** created in the task list and the one in the content type have different internal name: in the Content Type (coming from system *Task* Content Type) is *TaskDueDate* while the one created by default in the Task list is *DueDate*. 
The timeline works only with *DueDate* while the workflow can see only *TaskDueDate*.
So far I could not find a solution for this: can anybody suggest a workaround - or in case a different approach?

Thanks, Marco

attching the error message I get in the workflow
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Marco,

Perhaps another approach. Using SPD and workflows, I typically calculate the due date that is associated with the task:
[image]

Then place the variable in the task due date area.
Kind regards,

Comment: Thank MaxK, this could be a workaround, but I need a more reliable solution. As far as I have seen, the problem is that basically SP 2013 and later DO NOT WANT REUSABLE WORKFLOW... It is still possible to create them with a workaround, but then at re-editing them, they loose the connection with Content Type.
The only solution I have found is to create a list workflow on the actual list and copy-paste the single action in the reusable workflow. It worked for me.